# How to implement functional object construction in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have written a library of classes and now I'd like to add functional-style construction much like the XDocument, XElement, XAttribute classes in .NET. Can anyone point me at resources which would describe how to do this. I'm particularly interested in being able to construct objects from a Linq expression.

```
var graph =
    new MyClass("Root", from data in list select 
        new MyNodeClass(data.Id)
    );
```

I'm guessing the constructor would look like:

```
MyClass(string name, params object[] content) {}
```

but I'm not sure where to start in terms of processing the Linq statement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
MyClass(string name, params object[] content)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.children = new List<MyClass>();

    foreach (var arg in content)
    {
        if (arg is MyClass)
            children.Add(arg as MyClass);
        else if (arg is IEnumerable<MyClass>)
        {
            foreach (var element in args as IEnumerable<MyClass>)
                children.Add(element);
        }
        else
            children.Add(new MyClass(arg.ToString()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool. Interesting, so the Linq expression has `typeof IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @user1200984 More precisely LINQ expressions implements `IEnumerable<T>`. For example, in query `from a in new[] { 1, 2, 3 } where a % 2 == 0 select a` there're a few objects. First, `new[] { 1, 2, 3}` is the array of integers that implements `IEnumerable<int>`. Second, the method `Where` returns a decorator that also implements `IEnumerable<int>`.

Answer (score 2):

The signature should look like:

```
MyClass(string name, IEnumerable<MyNodeClass> content) {}
```

Beyond that, what do you want to do with `content` in your ctor?

(EDITTED -- thanks Magnus)

```
MyClass(string name, IEnumerable<MyNodeClass> content)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.children = content.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Well, for example if `list` contains 10 elements then MyClass.Children would contain 10 MyNodes. Like building an object graph of my classes using Linq.

Comment: Probably should be `IEnumerable<MyNodeClass>`

Answer (score 0):

I advice encapsulate the creating instanes of class MyNodeClass and write code like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(string name, IEnumerable<MyNodeClass> nodes)
    {
        //...
    }
}

public class MyNodeClass
{
    public MyNodeClass(int id)
    {
        //...
    }
}

public class MyNodes : IEnumerable<MyNodeClass>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<int> _data;
    public MyNodesClass(IEnumerable<int> data)
    {
        _data = data;
    }

    public IEnumerator<MyNodeClass> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var id in _data)
        {
            yield return new MyNodeClass(id);
        }

        //return (from id in _data
        //        select new MyNodeClass(id)).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Now you can do the same

```
var data = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var graph =
        new MyClass(
            "Root",
            new MyNodes(data)
        );
```

This more declarative